# How can I set UITabBarAppearance() without overriding UITabBarItem.appearance()?

Tags: ios, swift

I style my UITabBarItem titles globally as follows:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(TextStyle.tabTitle(colored: false).attributes, for: .normal)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(TextStyle.tabTitle(colored: true).attributes, for: .selected)
```

In iOS 15, I need to override the new behaviour where the tab bar background is hidden at the scroll edges. I can do that like this:

```
let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

However, this seems to override the font of the tab bar item titles, and reset them back to the default. I can't seem to override the tab bar hiding behaviour, and retain my custom font.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    let tabBarItemAppearance = UITabBarItemAppearance()
    tabBarItemAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [TextStyle.tabTitle(colored: false).attributes]
    tabBarItemAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [TextStyle.tabTitle(colored: false).attributes]
```

Comment: No, the UITabBarAppearance still overrides it when set that way. And it doesn't matter which is set first, UITabBarAppearance or UITabBarItemAppearance - either way the tab bar appearance seems to take priority.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. So you've created the `UITabBarItemAppearance ` object... Now how do you actually assign it to the TabBar?

Comment: I have a custom UITabBarController subclass. Not related to solving this issue, that's just the way the app is architected. I'm applying that tabBarAppearance to the tab bar in that controller, as in the code snippet in my question. But it would behave the same anyway it was applied - say for example, from a `viewController.tabBarController.tabBar`

It works - this overrides the new iOS 15 behaviour, and the tab bar is no longer made transparent at the scroll edges, as I want. But it also seems to override any font styling applied, which is the issue